# C++ How to call an object in one of its class method?

Tags: c++

sorry if the title is unclear, I'll try to explain my problem better here.

I created a class Unit :

```
class Unit {
   .
   .  (attributes)
   .
   public: 
    vector<Unit> getvoisins(Game Game0);
    vector<Unit> getgroupe(Game Game0);
};
```

And, in getgroupe, i have an issue, how do i refer to the Unit i'm applying the method to ? I started writing :

```
vector<Unit> Unit:: getgroupe(Game Game0) {
    vector<Unit> L;
    L.push_back( ???? );        
    return L;
}
```

How do I pushback the Unit in question? Like if I call `UnitA.getgroupe` I want the method to perform `L.push_back(UnitA)` (and then other things ofc) but I don't know how to write it. (what to replace ???? with ?)

Sorry if I haven't explained it well, or if the question was answered elsewhere yet, I couldn't find an answer cause I can't put words on the problem.

Comment: Note that it is common to start variables names with a lower case letter, thus `game0`  instead of `Game0`. Also single letter variables are also not very descriptive, and thus bad practice. Though an exception is made for counters used for example to iterate over a list.

Answer (score 4):

`this` is a pointer to the object you are currently calling the method for. `*this` is the object that pointer is pointing at.

In your case, this should work:

```
vector<Unit> Unit::getgroupe(Game _game0) // why the parameter?
{
    vector<Unit> L;
    L.push_back(*this); // the object of "This" current object

    return L;
}
```

Advice: Use proper variable names